# How to correctly connect a wire in the philips-hue not working bulb?

Tags: led, light-bulb

I simply have Philips Hue bulb which has stopped working. I tried to disassemble it, and I accidentally broke the wire (probably).

[image] [image]

Where should I solder it to? Could you point me that spot?

[image]

Comment: Usually a lot easier to just replace the bulb.  You would need to find where that wire was broken off from and then try to solder it back on.  Then you need to find why the bulb stopped working and replace that part.  Then you will need to try to put all the little parts back together only to find the bulb still does not work.

Comment: I know why it doesnt work. Because wire is broken. And that is all. There is nothing to replace. All I need to know is to find the spot where is should be solded back on.

Comment: Generally for a reputable brand name product you should get the whole intact product replaced under warranty, not void the warranty by ripping it open. Having ripped it open, if a wire is broken off, you look for the part with a broken wire stub, and that's where it goes. Whether you can get there outside of following the assembly procedure used in the factory is an unknown, and generally somewhere between difficult and impossible. Since the bulb stopped working *before* you disassembled it and broke the wire, it probably still won't work even if you reconnect the wire.

Comment: Agreed. Wire was broken during nrute-firce disassembly. You could find the place on the PCB where it reads attached, replace it, reassemble, and you would still not have a working bulb. Discard it unless you have the electronics skills to find the failed part, identify it, replaced it, and reassemble properly...  And even if you can do so it isn't _worth_ doing so except as a hobbyist hack.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an electronics question, note a jouse-wiring question, and therefore not a home improvement question

Answer (score 3):

The broken wire is in fact an inline fuse covered in heatshink tubing:
[image]

and should be connected to the center pin of the socket on one end:
[image]

and the other end to the pad on the PCB indicated by the red arrow below:
[image]

I would be a good idea for you to check that the fuse is still intact (using the continuity or resistance setting on your multimeter) before going to the trouble of soldering it back together.

The other wire should be connected to the large metal outer shell.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, and that is the answer I was waiting for;) You are master;)

Comment: Looks likely. Probably won't help. If the fuse blew,, then even if replaced it will probably just blow again unless the cause is corrected.